# NET 7.0; Masstransit consumer needs that a message get published multiple times by the publisher to get it

Tags: winforms, rabbitmq, masstransit, .net-7.0

I have this piece of code for Rabbitmq publisher:

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
{
    busConfigurator.SetEndpointNameFormatter(new KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter(prefix: "PS", includeNamespace: false));
   
    
    busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
    {
        configurator.Host(new Uri(builder.Configuration["MessageBroker:Host"]!), h =>
    {
        
        h.Username(builder.Configuration["MessageBroker:Username"]);
        h.Password(builder.Configuration["MessageBroker:Password"]);
        

    }
            );
        configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
    
});
```

and this configuration for the consumer app which is windows forms application:

```
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = IocConfig.CreateServiceProvider(services);
            IConfigurationManagerService configurationManager = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigurationManagerService>();
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<NotificationCreatedConsumer>();
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("ps-notification-created", e =>
                    {
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<NotificationCreatedConsumer>(context);
                    });
                    cfg.Host(configurationManager.Host, "/", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(configurationManager.RBUserName);
                        h.Password(configurationManager.RBPassword);
                    });
                    

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });
            
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();


        });
```

The windows forms application forms are running on a BackgroundService type class which is as below:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
    readonly IBusControl _bus;
    public Worker(IServiceProvider services, IBusControl bus)
    {
        this._services = services;
        _bus = bus;
    }
    
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fa-IR");

            // The following line provides localization for the application's user interface.  
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

            // The following line provides localization for data formats.  
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

            // Set this culture as the default culture for all threads in this application.  
            // Note: The following properties are supported in the .NET Framework 4.5+ 
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

            System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);





            var viewLogin = new ViewLogin();
            var presenter =
                new ViewLoginPresenter(viewLogin, _services.GetRequiredService<IQCApplicationController>());
            GridLocalizer.Active = new CustomGridLocalizer();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(viewLogin);
            

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("QualityControl", ex.StackTrace,
                System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            _bus.Stop();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    
}
```

and the consumer class `NotificationCreatedConsumer`:

```
public class NotificationCreatedConsumer : ViewModelBase, IConsumer<NotificationCreatedEvent>
{
    private readonly ICommunicationApplicationController _communicationAppController;
    private readonly IToastService _toastService;
    private readonly IActiveDirectoryService _activeDirectoryService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;
    private NotificationCreatedEvent _message;
    private NotificationDto notification;


    public event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> MessageReceived;
    public NotificationCreatedConsumer(
        ICommunicationApplicationController communicationAppController,
        IToastService toastService,
        IActiveDirectoryService activeDirectoryService,
        IMapper mapper,
        Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        _communicationAppController = communicationAppController;
        _toastService = toastService;
        _activeDirectoryService = activeDirectoryService;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    public NotificationDto Notification
    {
        get => notification;
        set
        {
            notification = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Notification));
            OnMessageReceived(nameof(Notification));
        }
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<NotificationCreatedEvent> context)
    {
        NotificationDto notifi = await _communicationAppController.GetNotificationByIdAsync(context.Message.Id);
        if (notifi == null)
        {

            return;
        }

       
        Notification = notifi;
        


    }

    private void OnMessageReceived(string propertyName)
    {

        MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Besides, the RabbitMq container is running on a remote computer. I wonder that why when I send a message of type `NotificationCreated` the consumer "sometimes" doesn't receive it.
What changes should I make to the configurations to receive all the messages sent to the consumer?